# No module named '_mysql_connector' using Django and mysql-connector-python 8.0.32

Tags: django, docker, mysql-connector

I have a Django 4.1 website that was running fine in a Docker container with MariaDB 10.5. I updated only the `mysql-connector-python` module from 8.0.29 to 8.0.32 but now when I start up the web container that runs Django's dev server I get:

```
myproject_web | Traceback (most recent call last):
myproject_web |   File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 64, in <module>
myproject_web |     import _mysql_connector
myproject_web | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_mysql_connector'
myproject_web | 
myproject_web | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
myproject_web | 
myproject_web | Traceback (most recent call last):
myproject_web |   File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 60, in <module>
myproject_web |     from mysql.connector.connection_cext import CMySQLConnection
myproject_web |   File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 81, in <module>
myproject_web |     raise ImportError(
myproject_web | ImportError: MySQL Connector/Python C Extension not available (No module named '_mysql_connector')
myproject_web | 
myproject_web | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
...
```

I'm not sure where the fault lies, having a sketchy understanding of database servers and their connectors etc. If I downgrade `mysql-connector-python` to 8.0.29 then it works again (I can't use 8.0.30 or 8.0.31 because of a utf8 issue that I'm hoping is fixed in 8.0.32). [Here is its changelog.](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/master/CHANGES.txt)

My `docker-compose.yml` has this for the database container:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    container_name: myproject_db
    env_file: .env
    image: mariadb:10.5
    ports:
      - 4306:3306
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

And my web container's `Dockerfile` starts:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-bullseye

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential git libpq-dev libmariadb-dev mariadb-client --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /usr/share/doc /usr/share/man \
    && apt-get clean
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here running Django 3.2-4.1 in Docker, on a Mac M1: "No module named '_mysql_connector'"

mysql-connector-python==8.0.31 and below runs correctly on all systems (native and Docker).

mysql-connector-python==8.0.32 runs correctly in Docker under Win10, and deploys successfully on our native Ubuntu servers. Only the Mac M1 generates the error.

The Win10 Docker container initializes with MySQL Docker Image 8.0.31-1.2.10-server, whereas the same Docker container on the Mac M1 shows "MySQL Docker Image 8.0.32-1.2.11-server".

Sorry these are just clues, but this seems like another M1 dependency issue.

Comment: Sorry, no progress to report.

Comment: This seems to be fixed in 8.1.0 version. See https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/8.1.0/

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue with Django 4.2.6 and mysql-connector-python 8.1.0. The issue was resolved by downgrading to mysql-connector-python 8.0.31

Comment: You say you had the issue with v8.1.0 but resolved it by downgrading to v8.1.0?

Comment: @PhilGyford sorry typo, updated. Ended up changing to using mysqlclient rather than mysql-connector-python anyway after further issues.